# Is it possible to run Docker Windows container and edit registry (regedit)?

Tags: windows, docker, registry

I'm new to Docker and started to read the official documentation & googled around the internet but couldn't find conclusive answer.

I'll describe my situation, I have a program (in C++) that runs as a service on Windows 10 Pro and have configuration details in windows registry (regedit).
Currently if I want to debug it I have a virtual machine of Win 10 Pro and use remote debug.
The reason I don't debug it on my machine is because my program always runs on my machine as a service and I don't want to stop it, also on the VM I edit/change the registry configuration.

So I was thinking using Docker instead of VM, but a question has arisen:
Is it possible to edit the container registry without changing/harming the host machine registry?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is passing mention in Microsoft Docs:

> While a container shares the host operating system's kernel, the container doesn't get unfettered access to it. Instead, the container gets an isolated–and in some cases virtualized–view of the system. For example, a container can access a virtualized version of the file system and registry, but any changes affect only the container and are discarded when it stops. To save data, the container can mount persistent storage such as an Azure Disk or a file share (including Azure Files).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/#how-containers-work

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot :)